# can the function of converting day of a year to date be run in loop?

Tags: python

Can the function of converting day of a year to date be run in loop?

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime       
    
     df = pd.read_csv('AS040719.57', header=None , sep=' ', names=["Date","Precipitation",], skipinitialspace=True )   
        year = "1957" 
        i = 0  
        for i in range (len(df.Date)):#to run till the end of the y
           day_num = df.Date[i]
           df.Date[i] = datetime.strptime(year + "-" + df.Date[i], "%Y-%j").strftime("%m-%d-%Y")  
        print(df.Date)  
          
        
        df.to_csv('ppt.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you want to use df.apply() instead of a loop if you can't use one of the built-ins `df['col'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` functionalities.

In this case you might try something like `df['col'].dt.strftime('1957-%m-%d')` if you want to hard code the year.

Comment: I tried that but it still shows an error with: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: Ah, just convert the column to a datetime type first.